# Matlab: how do I retrieve the title, the xlabel, the ylabel and font of a plotyy?

Tags: matlab, plot, properties, label, matlab-figure

I have some figures, for which I want to change:

1. The title
2. The xlabel and the ylabel (both font size and content)
3. The ticks size.

This is how I usually do it:

```
title('new title ');
xlhand = get(gca,'xlabel');
set(xlhand,'string','xlabel','fontsize',13);
ylhand = get(gca,'ylabel');
set(ylhand,'string','ylabel','fontsize',13);
set(gca,'FontSize',13);
```

It usually works fine. However, it doesn't work when I want to edit a plot made with the *ploty* function. The only effect is that my right *ylabel* changes.

I'm aware that since I have two *ylabels* now, changing them won't be as easy as for a normal plot. However, I'm surprised that I can't change the *xlabels* and the title. Why is that?

What's wrong with the above code in relation to the *plotxy* function? How can I make it work? The [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plotyy.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com) doesn't contain any relevant information.

I'm using Matlab R2015a.

**Edit:** Yes, I meant *plotyy* (there was a typo in my question). Here is sample code from the documentation:

```
x = 0:0.01:20;
y1 = 200*exp(-0.05*x).*sin(x);
y2 = 0.8*exp(-0.5*x).*sin(10*x);

figure % new figure
plotyy(x,y1,x,y2)
```

Comment: Do you mean `plotyy` instead of xyplot and plotxy? Could you [edit] your question to include sample code that generates the plot itself?

Comment: @Sardar_Usama Well, the OP talks about **two** *ylabels* which means that there must be two y-axis. The referenced Simscape function `plotxy` probably has only one of them as seen [here](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/physmod/simscape/ref/simscape.logging.plotxy.html). Consequently it does not make sense somehow... Therefore it would be good when the OP (1) clarifies (2) includes the code that is used to create the graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From documentation without using `get`, `set` :

```
x = 0:0.01:20;
y1 = 200*exp(-0.05*x).*sin(x);
y2 = 0.8*exp(-0.5*x).*sin(10*x);

figure % new figure
hAx = plotyy(x,y1,x,y2);

title('Multiple Decay Rates')
xlabel('Time (\musec)')

ylabel(hAx(1),'Slow Decay') % left y-axis
ylabel(hAx(2),'Fast Decay') % right y-axis
```

Then change values by

```
xlabel('New label','fontsize',10)
title('New Title','fontsize',10)
ylabel(hAx(2),'Fast Decay','fontsize',20)
hAx(1).FontSize=5
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the documentation, you can see that `plotyy` can return the axis handles. So first, you that option to obtain the handles:

```
Ax = plotyy(x,y1,x,y2);
```

Now, `Ax(1)` is the handle to the left  axes and `Ax(2)` is the right one. So you can change the attributes of each of them, for example

```
set(Ax(1),'FontSize',13);
```

For reasons I don't fully understand, setting the label is done using

```
set(get(Ax(1),'YLabel'),'String','Whatever you want...');
```

**EDIT:**

If you already plotted the data, you can retrieve the handles using

```
Ax = findobj(gcf,'type','axes')
```

Comment: I didn't make myself clear.  I'm sorry about that. I plotted my data some time ago and saved it in a *.fig file. Then I'd like to be able to change the listed options. I don't want to redraw the plot.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. And what about the title and the xaxis? Simple *title('my title')* doesn't work and I don't understand, why.

Comment: @user2738748 Try `title(Ax(1),'This is a title')` for the title and `ylabel(Ax(1),'Left label')` for the left label. For the x-label it would be `xlabel(Ax(1),'The x-label')`. Furthermore, `set(Ax,'FontSize',13)` would set the font size directly for both axes.